Discrete Real dimension spacing in scikit-optimize
Let's say I am searching over a dimension:
from skopt import space

search_space = [
    space.Real(1, 10, name="my_scale")
]

How can I make this Real number to be searched with discrete steps? E.g. 0.25. Because in my case, calculating data for each real value can be cached and I know that fine-tuning the value with small steps like 0.00001 does not give meaningful improvements. However if the value is calculated 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, etc. I can cache the results and speed up the optimisation process a lot.
E.g. something like

search_space = [
    space.Real(1, 10, step=0.25, name="my_scale")
]


No I did not run it. This was the only answer that had a level of sophistication where author demonstrated they had understood my question in the first place.

Thank you for pointing out the issue. But I am pretty sure any boundary issues with this I can fix myself.

please do that. I would be happy to see an actually working solution (that runs faster than the answer using Categorical with gp_optimize), instead of something that merely looks sophisticated to rake in the bounty.

Thank you @ChristophRackwitz - I will modify the code to suit to my needs and then later publish the result in another answer. Just to clarify is there a difference between Real and Categorical search space and where is the relevant code in skopt and I can take a closer look myself.

I don't have a lot of experience with skopt but I'm wondering whether something like this would help you:
def generate_discrete_values(start, end, step):
    values = []
    while start <= end:
        values.append(round(start, 2))
        start += step
    return values

Subsequently, I would feed that into skopt though I am checking how do that  - I am reviewing the API.
Will update...
